# ROS Hydro - Cannot commit gscam camera calibration (/set_camera_info not under /camera)

Tags: calibration, gscam, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I started using ROS hydro (in ubuntu 12.04) very recently for a visual odometry project but I got stuck with the following problem:

I installed gscam and it runs fine (or at least I think so because I can get the raw image from the cam) but when I try to calibrate it using the camera_calibration package I get an error about the set_camera_info when trying to commit.

This are the commands I’m using (and the responses I’m getting):

```
ire@ubuntu:/opt/ros/hydro/share/gscam$ export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"
ire@ubuntu:/opt/ros/hydro/share/gscam$ rosrun gscam gscam
[ INFO] [1413532922.860687013]: Using gstreamer config from env: "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"
[ INFO] [1413532922.865519517]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1413532922.865710842]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/ire/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1413532922.865894433]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/ire/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1413532922.866022619]: Camera calibration file /home/ire/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1413532922.866143973]: Loaded camera calibration from 
[ WARN] [1413532922.867056658]: No camera frame_id set, using frame "/camera_frame".
[ INFO] [1413532922.931583052]: Time offset: 1413532776.252
[ INFO] [1413532923.433639353]: Publishing stream...
[ INFO] [1413532923.440739002]: Started stream.
```

At this point the light on my camera turns on and if I run the *rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw* the camera works.

I checked the topics and services and this is what I got:

```
ire@ubuntu:~$ rostopic list
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
ire@ubuntu:~$ rosservice list
/camera/image_raw/compressed/set_parameters
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/camera/image_raw/theora/set_parameters
/gscam_publisher/get_loggers
/gscam_publisher/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
/set_camera_info
```

As you can see the */set_camera_info* service is not under */camera* like it’s apparently supposed to be (I’m not sure if it is, that’s just the conclusion I got to). So I run the camera calibration with the following command:

```
ire@ubuntu:~$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=
```

But after finishing and trying to commit I get this error:

```
 raise ServiceException("service [%s] unavailable"%self.resolved_name)
rospy.service.ServiceException: service [/camera/set_camera_info] unavailable
```

I’ve tried changing the parameters in the camera_calibration command, using camera_info:= instead of camera:= and so on, but I always get the same mistake when trying to commit. If I use **camera:=camera** or **camera_info:=camera** as parameters the calibration cannot start because the set_camera_info service is not under /camera. If I ignore the check with  **--no-service-check** I still get the same mistake at the end.

I’m pretty new with ROS, so I’m sorry if the question is too silly. I really tried to find the answer myself but I don’t know what to do about the service not being under /camera like (i think) the calibration tool needs.

Is there a way to put the service under /camera? or another way to calibrate the camera without using commit? I can save the file, but is it .tar format and I have not being able to find a way to use it yet. I’m really thankful for any ideas you might have.

ps: I don’t know if it might be the cause of my problem but I’m running ubuntu in a Parallels virtual machine, sometimes it gets a bit slow but so far I haven’t run into any problems with other programs because of it.

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195217/ros-hydro---cannot-commit-gscam-camera-calibration-(/set_camera_info-not-under-/camera)/) by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2014-10-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can move ros resources using remapping. Both from the [command line](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) and [from a launch file](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1